# Azure Build Pipeline: How to include additional project in artifact?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

My solution has 2 projects: 1 web application and a console application. The console application should run every 15 minutes.

Ideally I want to put the build output (binaries) of the console application inside the web application folder: app_data\jobs\continuous\job1 (trying to follow the azure web jobs tutorial)

I setup the build pipeline to build the solution and then setup the release pipeline to deploy the build.

However, in the build log, I see that the "Build Solution task" in the build pipeline builds the web application, packages it into a ZIP file and then builds the console application. In the zip artifact that is generated, the console application binaries are missing.

How do I get it to include the console app build output inside the app_data folder?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task and copy the compiled console app to the folder you use as `PathtoPublish` in the `Publish artifact` step. This way it would be included in the ZIP and you could use it in the deployment pipeline.

Here's an example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
     **\[path_to_your_project]\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**

    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```